"Extra attributes from the server: bis_register" warning in Next 14
I initialized a Next 14 app with create-next-app with Typescript and Tailwind and there's that warning on the console and i have no idea how to fix it or even what it means.
I didn't change a single file. I just ran the installation command, then npm run dev and there's that warning there. No matter whether i'm rendering the default template or a literal blank page with not a single element, the warning won't go away. Thanks in advance.

Could you please clarify your question by adding some more context into it, like which type of warning or screenshots etc.
